# how to collect maximum and minimum values from a grep search pattern using bash?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a huge log.txt file from which I need to calculate the maximum and minimum values.

```
 0-00:42:35.598 <tc_testcase>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]: tc_testcase.c:8963: VERIFY_CASE: range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0[1](a, 1)=121, (0)=0, (25000)=25000, (ok)
 0-00:42:35.598 <tc_testcase>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]: tc_testcase.c:8963: VERIFY_CASE: range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0[1](a, 1)=256879, (0)=0, (25000)=25000, (ok)
 0-00:42:35.598 <tc_testcase>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]: tc_testcase.c:8963: VERIFY_CASE: range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0[1](a, 1)=2300, (0)=0, (25000)=25000, (ok)
 0-00:42:35.598 <tc_testcase>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]: tc_testcase.c:8963: VERIFY_CASE: range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0[1](a, 1)=56897132, (0)=0, (25000)=25000, (ok)
 0-00:42:35.598 <tc_testcase>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]: tc_testcase.c:8963: VERIFY_CASE: range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0[1](a, 1)=12579, (0)=0, (25000)=25000, (ok)
 0-00:42:35.598 <tc_testcase>:[DEFAULT]:[PRINT]: tc_testcase.c:8963: VERIFY_CASE: range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0[1](a, 1)=968746, (0)=0, (25000)=25000, (ok)
```

so, as the first step I started to collect lines as below into a separate file with the below grep command and later to sort it:

```
 grep -Po '.X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0.*[1].*(a, 1).\K.*' file.txt > collect.txt
```

But the output I receive is quite different. It looks something like this:-

```
=121, (25000)=25000, (ok)
=256879, (25000)=25000, (ok)
=2300, (25000)=25000, (ok)
=56897132, (25000)=25000, (ok)
=12579, (25000)=25000, (ok)
=968746, (25000)=25000, (ok)
```

Expected should be:-

```
121
256879
2300
56897132
12579
968746
```

Can anyone help to modify the current grep command i'm using to collect the values as the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just needed to escape the special regex characters :

```
grep -Po 'range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0\[1\]\(a, \d\)=\K\d+' file.txt
121
256879
2300
56897132
12579
968746
```

For such a case (*to me*) **Perl** itself is preferable :

```
perl -lne '/ \d\)=\K\d+/ && print $&' file.txt
121
256879
2300
56897132
12579
968746
```

and for **min** and **max** something like this:

```
perl -lne '/ \d\)=\K\d+/g && push(@number,$&); END{ print "@{[sort {$a <=> $b} @number]}[0,-1]"}' file.txt
121 56897132
```

and *END { ... }* means **sort** them and take out `0` and `last` index of the array of `@number`

For `sort` using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and not **Perl** to have **min** and **max** you can pipe your output to:

```
... | { mapfile -t arr; paste <(sort -n <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<  ${arr[@]})) <(sort -rn <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<  ${arr[@]})); }
121 56897132
2300    968746
12579   256879
256879  12579
968746  2300
56897132    121
```

which creates an array and then `sort` it twice. Then just pipe it to `head -n 1` e.g.

```
... | head -n 1
121 56897132
```

Comment: it works. Thanks it works. i'm using something like this to sort `grep -Po 'range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0\[1\]\(a, \d\)=\K\d+' file.txt
| sort -hr | sed -n '1p;$p`

But generally asking what is the difference between ".*" and "\" usage in grep?

Comment: this `.*` is a **greedy match** which means match as much as you can. and backslash is just for escaping special character e.g. `(a, 1)` here `(` and `)` are special and since you want to match them in your content you should **escape** with `\`

Answer (score 6):

You were close, trying to fix OP's attempt here. This could be done in GNU `grep` like following. We could use GNU `grep`'s `-P` option to enable PCRE regex there.

```
grep -oP '.*range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0\[1\]\([a-zA-Z]+, \d+\)=\K\d+'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, firstly enabling `-oP` options for GNU `grep` to enable PCRE regex capabilities and to get only matched values. Then in main program of grep, using regex `.*range: X_PER_Y_USER_RANGE_0\[1\]\([a-zA-Z]+, \d+\)=` to match everything from starting to till (), note here escaping part of `[`, `]`,`(`,`)` to make those characters as literal ones. Then using `\K` option to forget all the matched values till now. Mentioning `\d+` will match digits after it which is OP's actual requirement to get the digits.